# How do I turn off "get notifications from apps and other senders" in Windows 10 permanently?

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I'm using Windows 10 (Anniversary Update + plus recent updates) and I like to have the setting "get notifications from apps and other senders" turned off. Every time I reboot Windows, this setting gets switched from "off" to "on". How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @michalkralik describes how to turn off
"get notifications from apps and other senders".
This is probably equivalent to your turning it off yourself, which you say
lasts only until the next boot.

If some stronger setting is required,
the article [How to disable Notification and Action Center in Windows 10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-disable-notification-and-action-center-in-windows-10) shows how to totally disable the Action Center and all its notifications by setting in the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Explor‌​er` the DWORD item `DisableNotificationCenter` to 1.

Comment: This worked as you described and is a good enough solution for now. Thank you.

Comment: Spoke too soon. Something re-activated the Action Center and Notifications. I sure wish I could figure out what's doing it.

Comment: As an aside, nothing shows up in virus/spyware/malware scans per Windows Defender and Malwarebytes.

Comment: Interesting: What has happened to this registry key - has it been deleted or has its value changed? It's possible that a Windows Update has changed something.

Comment: [The value is still set to 1](http://i.imgur.com/igKOpgF.png)

Comment: Well, it seems that Microsoft in its god-like wisdom has disabled this option. It's pretty hard working with an operating system where features change without warning, and no way to know if this was intentional or a bug. You could put the code by @michalkralik in a .bat file inside the Startup folder. But, apparently with the forthcoming Windows 10 Creators Update you will need to specifically enable DOS or .bat files will also stop working. What Microsoft now does can only be called harassment.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to turn off the notifications

```
Reg Add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications" /v ToastEnabled /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

This sets `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications\ToastEnabled` registry key to value `0` and disables "get notifications from apps and other senders".

You need to restart Windows for this to take effect.

Comment: I will try and let you know what happens.

Comment: This did not work, a restart makes the setting come back to "on".

Answer (score 0):

Searched for this several times, and could not find an answer which worked. So today I decided to do this the "debug" way:
In a VirtualMachine with Windows:

1. Open regedit and export the complete registry; close regedit
2. Go to Settings -> Notifications & actions
3. disable everything you don´t want or need
4. Open regedit again and export the complete registry again
5. Use a diff program like BeyondCompare to find the differences, filter out the ones which do not fit

This left me with the changes as shown in the following picture (I greyed the ID following HKEY_USERS as it is most probably different for your user):
[Which notification setting changes which registry value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0B4c.png)

Then I used another VirtualMachine with a freshly installed windows (tested with Windows 10 2004), and only changed the Reg values there. After a restart (this is probably possible even before that), I provoked a Notification, but nothing did occur. Changing the reg-key back and forth and provoking the notification showed it with Notifications turned on, and again did not show it after turning it off.
So this is working for me.